# Effect of "Thran Lens" on Devotion

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I want to know the effects of [Thran Lens](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thran%20Lens) on a devotion-dependent enchantment creature, like a god or something.

I read somewhere that, when a permanent becomes colorless, the Thran Lens makes the 'cost symbols' turn into 'colorless'. With this in mind, if I have [Heliod, God of the Sun](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Heliod%2C%20God%20of%20the%20Sun) on the battlefield will he ever be a creature while Thran Lens is on the battlefield?

Comment: I made some edits to your second paragraph to make the question more clear, feel free to roll it back if you don't like it.

Comment: By the way, if you write card names like `[mtg:Card Name]`, then the system will automatically turn it into a card link. Easy, right? Someone else went ahead and did it for you this time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mana cost and color are two completely separate characteristics. [Thran Lens](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thran%20Lens) only modifies the color, not the mana cost, and so Thran Lens has no effect on devotion.

**Devotion**

> 700.5. A player’s devotion to [color] is equal to the number of mana symbols of that color among the mana costs of permanents that player controls.

**Mana Cost**

> 202.1. A card’s mana cost is indicated by mana symbols near the top of the card.

**Color**

> 202.2. An object is the color or colors of the mana symbols in its mana cost, regardless of the color of its frame.

> 202.2f Effects may change an object’s color, give a color to a colorless object, or make a colored object become colorless

Answer (score 6):

All the Thran Lens does is make permanents colorless, it doesn't change their casting costs at all. Devotion counts the number of colored mana symbols in a permanents casting cost, it doesn't care what color the permanent is.

Your Heliod will animate just fine even is everything on the battlefield is colorless assuming there are enough white mana symbols among the permanents you control.

> **700.5.** A player’s devotion to [color] is equal to the number of mana symbols of that color among the mana costs of permanents that player controls. A player’s devotion to [color 1] and [color 2] is equal to the number of mana symbols among the mana costs of permanents that player controls that are [color 1], [color 2], or both colors.

Answer (score 4):

**Thran Lens or other color-changing effects have no effect on Devotion.**

> 700.5. A player’s devotion to [color] is equal to the number of mana symbols of that color among the mana costs of permanents that player controls.

The mana symbols in a card's mana cost determine the card's color, but not the other way around.

> 105.3. Effects may change an object’s color or give a color to a colorless object. If an effect gives an object a new color, the new color replaces all previous colors the object had (unless the effect said the object became that color “in addition” to its other colors). Effects may also make a colored object become colorless.

The above rule covers everything about changing an object's color. Note that it does not say anything about mana symbols being changed, so nothing like that happens.